# In wordpress how to get the values from custom post type based on taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

I need to get the values in my page template from custom post type based on taxonomy.

In my project am having four taxonomy  as china,japan, singapore, malaysia

Each taxonomy has separate value

Need to retrive the datas accordingly.

**For example:**

**China:**

```
Name1
address1

Name2
address2
```

**Malaysia:**

```
Name1
address1

Name2
address2
```

and so on.

Kindly suggest some ideas for that.
Thanks.

Comment: How are the names and addresses entered? via a custom field?

Comment: yes name and address are custom fields only

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through the custom post type of 'country' which are tagged with "china".

```
// WP_Query Arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => array( 'country' ),
    'tag_id'                 => 'china',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query($args);

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    echo '<h1>'.the_title().'</h1>';
    echo $customField[1];
    echo $customField[2];

endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
```